# Advice on functional React best practices

Tags: reactjs

I started working with React a few months ago. Coming from an Angular background it took a bit to get used to react concepts but I started enjoying it super fast.
Over the past two months I have refactored some class based components to functional components using React hooks. I am looking for advice on some best practices here since I am fairly new to functional hooks and there is not a whole lot of solid opinions on best practices. Here are a few

1. With regards to “unit” testing. the instance in functional React does not exist. I can’t call a function and test it independent of other methods. React now suggests that “we recommend using react-testing-library which is designed to encourage writing tests that use your components as the end users do.” This approach seems more like end to end testing to me. I have certain functions that that do a number of calculation and save to state without any visual changes and re-rendering. How should I test those functions?
2. I have read that I need to  move some of my functions outside of the main exported function and call them in order to have them return a value to update the state with. Is this good practice? Should I export all of these outside functions in order to be able to test them or is this bad practice? If not how do I get to test these pure functions. I have created a very simple example of the pattern I am talking about here 
   https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-currying-v09bb

I would love to know your opinions and how you have managed to solve these problems. Any thoughts or insight
Is much appreciated.

Comment: _certain functions that that do a number of calculation and save to state without any visual changes_, as far as UI is concerned, these are just implementation details, testing these will result in brittle tests. Instead test what the user would perceive from these calculations

Comment: but sometimes these pure functions output don't have visual changes or don't cause a re-render. I understand the value of an end to end user center testing. Are we suggesting that the only test needed for React apps are these user centered tests? clicking on something and expecting something to change in the browser?

Comment: Thats not entirely true. The DOM change in bind to the state of the component. If there is a state change in the component and it has been lined to pure function using props, the DOM will update

Answer (score 1):

You and I are on same boat as since we both have moved to React from Angular. Considering the points you mentioned I would like to share some practices we have been following in our react projects. This has helped us to reduce much efforts in finding and fixing the bugs. Also we could achieve 100% test coverage.

> 1. Always create a common libs and keep all the function which has mostly a business logic but no DOM impacts. This reduces the size of stateful components and makes code much better to deal with unit testing.
> 2. Stateful component should never have bulk UI JSX. Always create stateless component (pure component) for UI and handle them all though
>      the container.
> 3. Avoid creating functions which returns the pure HTML (JSX). Crate a different file and return a stateless component from there. This
>      makes Unit testing easy.

This again is entirely depend on the your project structure. In Angular you work with certain set of pre-defined rules of Angular and Test tools like Protractor makes it easy to test.

However React comes with more flexible development approach which has its own downside. If developer do not keep hold on the way he/she writing the app, it gets into a chaotic situation.

PS: I use JEST for the testing and it does job well in terms of unit testing. I also use `cypress` for UI automation which is a great tool for react UI automation.

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you for your help. That makes sense. I started to use Cypress this week and will look into the architecture that you suggested. I think the issue is that I come from a background of opinionated frameworks and React is a bit of a wild wild west :)